# Turing test in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, artificial-intelligence, computers, star-trek-eu

For the benefit of those unacquainted with the [Turing Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test), it is a test proposed by computer scientist and philosopher Alan Turing. The idea was that a person would talk with a computer, unaware of who/what they were talking to. If, at the end of the conversation the person is unable to determine whether they were talking to a human or a robot (i.e. the computer has fooled the questioner into thinking they're a person) then they're said to have passed a key measure of sentience.

Now, after a search on Memory Alpha, I've found no references to the Turing test which got me thinking : ***When was the Turing test passed in Star Trek?***

I would expect it to be passed before the time of Lore (e.g. 2330s) considering he would pass the test.  I want to know if there was any reference in Star Trek materials (i.e. TV episodes, movies, comics, books) to the Turing Test and, if so what this reference involved.

Comment: Humanity's quest to develop a Turing capable intelligence was halted when we encountered the Vulcans. They already had advanced computers on their ships.

Comment: The earliest Turing-capable computer would be the Voyager computer. It was present at the Big Bang; http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Death_Wish_(episode)

Comment: The Turing Test has been passed in real-life, although not in any way we care about:  Someone wrote a bot that responded IN ALL CAPS and **LOTS** OF _SUPERFLUOUS PUNCTUTATION_, and used tons of frelling insults and intentionally bad grammar.  Basically, it acted like an immature 13-year-old, and everyone voted that it was a human.

Comment: Oh, and then there was [that psychologist that was tricked and led on for months on a dating website](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/the-switch/wp/2013/08/13/on-the-internet-no-one-knows-youre-a-bot-and-thats-a-problem/).

Comment: ([Transcript of the interview with that psychologist here](http://clubecetico.org/forum/index.php?topic=18037.0))

Comment: Come on, I have met actual people who cannot pass a Turing test. Well they seemed people, at least...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Within the Trek universe, [machine intelligence](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) is a regular feature. That said, there doesn't seem to be a specific instance when the "Turing threshold" was reached, nor is it generally used as a measure (as evidenced by the complete lack of a mention in any of the Trek TV episodes).

In the books it's mentioned on several occasions;

In [Typhon Pact](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Seize_the_Fire), Riker points out that Starfleet is now trivially capable of creating holograms that can pass it;

> “Really?” Riker said. “Copies of Starfleet’s early-model Emergency
>   Medical Holograms are routinely passing the Turing Test. Some of them
>   are even demanding full civil rights under the guarantees of the
>   Federation Constitution. There’s nothing ‘mere’ about that.”

In "[The Joy Machine](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Joy_Machine)", Kirk is clueless about it (despite being a [computer genius](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32332/where-else-do-we-see-james-t-kirk-computer-hacker-extraordinnaire));

> “The Turing test,” Linda said.
>
> “What’s that?” [Said Kirk]
>
> “If it responds in ways indistinguishable from those provided by a
>   sentient being, it must be sentient,” Linda said. “But it isn’t the
>   same thing. Sentient beings can’t be reprogrammed.”

In [Valhalla](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Valhalla), Mile O'Brien is scornful of it;

> O'Brien looked pained. "Lieutenant Dax, the last I heard, those
>   experts of yours were still trying variants on the Turing test, which
>   is centuries old and couldn't even prove that people are self-aware.
>   And if you'd ever dealt with androids, as I have..."

As far as further references are concerned, the Trek Book "[Brave New World](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Brave_New_World)" has extensive mentions of the new *android home-world*, originally the centre of the Iconian Empire but now renamed "**Turing**" in honour of the real-world scientist.

Comment: Excellent use of links and quotes: a very well researched and comprehensive answer, as always ;)

Comment: +1 for quoting *The Joy Machine*. One of, if not the, best *Trek* novels.